# Order string by name without using array in Java

Tags: java, string, compareto

I have a string which look like this :

```
String myString = 
    "1|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n" + 
    "2|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n" + 
    "3|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n" + 
    "4|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n";
```

In my assignment I can't use arrays or other classes than `String` and `System`.

I need to order names alphabetically using `compareTo` method.

I have a method that retrieve the name from the string which is:

```
public static String getContactName (String contact) {
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(contact, "|");
        String id = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String name = tokenizer.nextToken();
       
        return name;  
}
```

I have another method that insert the contact in the string. It's here that I have to use the `compareTo` method.

```
 public static String insertContactInString (String myString, String line) {
        int resultat = 0;
        String nomContact = "";
        String nomCarnet = "";
        String contact = "";
    
        if (myString != null) {
              myString += line + "\n";
              do  {
                    nomContact = getContactName(line);
                    nomCarnet = getContactName(myString);
    
                    resultat = nomContact.compareToIgnoreCase(nomCarnet);

                    if(resultat < 0) {
                          line = "|" + nomContact;
                          int pipe = line.lastIndexOf("|");
                          contact =contactLigne.substring(0,pipe);
                          line = contact;
                          line = "|" + nomCarnet;
                          pipe = line.lastIndexOf("|");
                          contact = line.substring(0,pipe);
                          line = contact;    
                     } else {
                          contact = "|" + nomCarnet;
                          int pipe = contact.lastIndexOf("|");
                          contact =contact.substring(0,pipe);
                          contact = contact;
                          contactLigne = "|" + nomContact;
                          pipe = contactLigne.lastIndexOf("|");
                          contact = contactLigne.substring(0,pipe);
                          contactLigne = contact;
                     }
    
             } while (resultat > 0);
               
             myString += line + "\n";
             System.out.println(myString);
       }
    
       return myString;  
 }
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me with my code, because now each substring is not ordered alphabetically in the String.

What I'm trying to do in the `insertContactInString` method is using `getContactName` to compare the name that is contained in the line parameter which is passed in parameter to the name contained in `myString` using same `getContactName` method.

To compare both strings, `myString` has to be not empty and contains at least one entry.

After that, I use `compareToIgnoreCase` to compare both strings and store the result in the `resultat` variable.

Here I use an if statement to check if `resultat` is less than zero. If it's the case, `nomContact` should insert before `nomCarnet` and if `resultat` is greater than zero, `nomCarnet` should be first followed by `nomContact`.

However, what I'm not able to do is to concatenate the name substring which is returned by `getContactName` with the line in `myString`.

For example, if the `resultat` is less than zero, I want to insert in `myString` the line that contains `nomContact` before the line that contains `nomCarnet` in a way that `myString` will look like this at the end:

```
String myString = 
    "3|nomContact|lastname|email|tel" + "\n" + 
    "2|nomCarnet|lastname|email|tel" + "\n" + 
    "1|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n" + 
    "4|name|lastname|email|tel" + "\n";
```

nom = name in english

Comment: This is pretty insane, and looks like mere busy work to me.  Personally I'd consider skipping this assignment altogether.  For the code, something you might want to do is to make your string more "array like" with methods to `get` a particular line and to `set` a particular line to a given value.  And also break your code up into smaller methods more generally, it's hard to read and debug right now.

Comment: You wrote, "...I can't use arrays or other classes than String and System" yet you're using `StringTokenizer`. Do you mean you can't use collection-type objects like arrays and `ArrayList` but other classes are ok?  Will the input always have 4 entries or must your solution work for any number of entries?

Comment: It is forbidden to use collections and any arrays We are allowed to use String Tokenizer but any other classes than String and System are not allowed. The solution has to work with any number of entries.

Comment: For example, if the entry is 4|Doe|John|3063543030|john@gmail.com and in the string there's already these two substrings :

Comment: 1|Aaron|Peter|3063543030|john@gmail.com+"\n" 2|Buffet|Anthony|3063543030|john@gmail.com+"\n 3|Dunty|Richard|3063543030|john@gmail.com + "\n"

Comment: 4|Doe|John|3063543030|john@gmail.com will be compare and inserted before 3|Dunty|Richard|3063543030|john@gmail.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using compareToIgnoreCase() to compare an entry to substring in string without using array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64948447/using-comparetoignorecase-to-compare-an-entry-to-substring-in-string-without-u)